# I am trying to insert data to the database in every 10 milisecond in a loop. So how can i wait between every inserting

Tags: java

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
        public String save(@ModelAttribute("emp") Employee emp){    
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            dao.save(emp); 
            }
            return "redirect:/viewemp";//will redirect to viewemp request mapping    
        }
```

here I want to wait 10 milisecond after the method:

```
dao.save(emp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pause then use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for one second or

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for a minute.

As this is a loop, this presents an inherent problem - drift. Every time you run code and then sleep you will be drifting a little bit from running, say, every second. If this is an issue then don't use `sleep`.

Further, `sleep` isn't very flexible when it comes to control.

For running a task every second or at a one second delay I would **strongly** recommend a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and either [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

For example, to run the method `myTask` every second (Java 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(App::myTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void myTask() {
    System.out.println("Running");
}
```

And in Java 7:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTask();
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static void myTask() {
    System.out.println("Running");
}
```